# A Question on Resistance

Tags: power, audio, resistance

A 19 v dc supply is switched to an IC amplifier. A 12 V dc, 100mA pilot lamp,(nonLED)is wired in parallel with the switch to indicate an active circuit. What size resistor is needed to support the pilot lamp ? My research indicates 70 ohm, but I am a newb.

Comment: What IC amplifier? Do you have a schematic of the circuit?

Comment: TPA 3116 Class D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lamp and its series ballast resistor are wired in parallel with the switch, when the switch is made - supplying power to the opamp - the lamp will extinguish, giving an indication that  power to the circuit has been turned OFF, when the opposite will be true.

Conversely, when the switch is opened, [some] power will be supplied to the opamp through the lamp and its ballast resistor, keeping the circuit from being turned OFF completely.  The lamp may or may not glow dimly, depending on the current drawn by the circuitry on the cold side of the switch.

To be wired into the circuit properly, the lamp and its ballast should be wired in parallel with the opamp:

[image]

Comment: EM, To my knowledge the proposed lamp does not have a ballast. It is a simple, 2 wire, 12volt dc pilot lamp, or perhaps I am ignorant of some aspect of the lamps construction, Regards,

Comment: The [ballast resistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_ballast) is the external 70 ohm resistor in series with the lamp

Comment: EM, If I understand correctly, the symbol to the right of the lamp is the "opamp" ?

Comment: Yes. I let the inputs and output float because only the power supply terminals are relevant here.

Comment: EM, Many thanks ! Your additional info helped to clarify what Logan said.

Answer (score 0):

Your math is correct. Since we have

Ohm's Law \$V = IR\$

For the lightbulb:

\$12V = 100mA * R\$

Solving for R we get

\$R = \frac{12V}{0.1A}\$
or
\$R = 120\Omega\$

Adding a \$70\Omega\$ resistor in series makes the total resistance across the 19V supply \$190\Omega\$.

Using \$V = IR\$ again, we can see that 
\$I = \frac{V}{R}\$ so the current flowing through the series circuit is \$\frac{19V}{190\Omega}\ = 0.1A \$ as shown by the ammeter.

We can also double check the voltage across the lightbulb is 12V.

I would guess the 100mA is a typical or MAX value, and by increasing the series resistor (R1) you could dim the lightbulb, possibly extending it's life.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8WT63.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Lamp1 and R1 aren't connected in parallel with sw1.

Comment: @EMFields true, I read it as an indicator light showing when the amplifier was powered, therefore - in parallel with the load (amp). I didn't show the load in my circuit, but feel everything else is still valid.

Comment: @LoganCummings: My point wasn't whether your your circuit worked the way you thought the OP wanted it to work, it was that it didn't conform to the OP's circuit description, of which no mention was made.